# Ultisnips not working with space

Tags: regular-expression, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I have the following snippet

```
context "math()"
snippet `v([a-zA-Z]) ` "bb" A
``rv = '\\mathbf{' + m[1] + '}'`` 
endsnippet
```

Now, most of my snippets work, however, snippets with regex that ends with `space` do not exectute properly. When writing `va` + `space`, I get `va`  instead of `\mathbf{a}`. I previously used hypersnips in vscode, for which this code worked. Does anyone know where is the issue?

NB: Any input of the form '`text*space*`' doesn't seem to be recognized when written as 'text ' in the snippet section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with the syntax. Though HyperSnips is inspired by UltiSnips, there are notable differences between them.  In particular,

- For regex snippets, you need to specify the `r` flag
- There are various forms of interpolation (shell, python, vim) in Ultisnips. The most flexible of these is python interpolation, which allows access to regex match groups (and a host of other things)
- For python interpolation, use `` `!p ...` `` in place of `` `...` ``, and
- `snip.rv` in place of `rv`
- match groups are accessible with `match.group()`

For more, see

- `:h UltiSnips-snippet-options`
- `:h UltiSnips-python`

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I have now managed to get the snippets running. Do you by any chance know how can I disable the # functionality? Whenever I have in a snippet it has a delay, taht is, when I type test#, the cursor moves infront of the pound key, waits one second, and then executes.

Comment: @MathsWizzard Welcome to the site! Glad you got the snippets running :) If this answered your question, feel free to mark it as an answer. Alternatively, you may answer your own question. Regarding the other question, I guess that there is an insert mode mapping containing `#`. Could you ask a separate question for that?

Comment: Hi, I have now marked the question as answered. I will link the other question in a second.

Comment: Hi @husB, here is the link https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/37111/vim-and-ultisnips-delay-with-pound-key