# VIM and UltiSnips delay with pound "#" key

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, snippets

Consider the following snippet

```
context "math()"
snippet "([a-zA-Z])#" "Vectors" riA
\mathbf{`!p snip.rv=match.group(1)`} 
endsnippet
```

The expected behaviour is that if I write `A#` I get  `\mathbf{A}` immediately, however, when I type that the cursor goes in front of `#` and then after a second it goes behind it and the snippet is executed.

Does anybody know how can I fix that?

Comment: It sounds like this is related to tex (or latex). Anyway, does this behavior still occur with all plugins disabled (if any)?

Comment: Hi, do you know how can I temporarily disable the plugins to check?

Comment: @MathsWizzard depends on how you installed them, probably. `vim -u DEFAULTS` loads without any plugins; then you can manually load ultisnips with the `:runtime` commands. This sort of delay is commonly observed when there are mappings or abbreviations that start with the same prefix, so that's another place to investigate.

Comment: @MathsWizzard If you are using a plugin manager (eg. packer/vim-plug/pathogen), just comment out the necessary lines. Alternatively if you are using vim8's package management feature, move the plugins from start/ to opt/

Comment: Some plugins can be disabled by setting a variable. For example, vimtex can be disabled with `let g:vimtex_enabled = 0`. Refer to each plugin's help page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My hunch is that you are using vimtex with Ultisnips. While this answer assumes that the behavior comes from vimtex, I recommended to diagnose what exactly is causing this behavior.

---

[This thread](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2003/how-do-i-debug-my-vimrc-file) details how to find out the specific plugin, or the line in one's config, that causes such a behavior.

Alternatively, a delay in execution suggests that there is a mapping that interferes with it, as alluded by Ben in the comments. This can be investigated with `:verbose imap <char>`. (Note that `imap <char>` will list the mappings starting with `<char>`, and the use of `:verbose` will show where the mapping was created.)

---

Now, assuming the behavior is due to vimtex, `:verbose imap #` will return

```
i  #B          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#B", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathbb"))
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim line 119
i  #-          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#-", vimtex#imaps#style_math("overline"))
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim line 119
i  #c          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#c", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathcal"))
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim line 119
i  #f          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#f", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathfrak"))
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim line 119
i  #b          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#b", vimtex#imaps#style_math("mathbf"))
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim line 119
i  #/          *@vimtex#imaps#wrap_math("#/", vimtex#imaps#style_math("slashed"))
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/vimtex/autoload/vimtex/imaps.vim line 119
```

Hence, after `#` is pressed in insert mode, vim waits for a set time, as the next key may correspond to one of the maps listed above. (For example, the user may press `#` followed by `b`, which results in `\mathbf{...}`). *This is why there is a delay after `#` is pressed (on its own), before # is actually inserted.*

---

The output from `:verbose imap` also gives us a big clue how to resolve the issue. Searching within VimTeX's documentation `:h vimtex` for "imap", we see

> INSERT MODE MAPPINGS                 *vimtex-imaps*
>
> Some LaTeX commands are very common, and so it is both natural and convenient
> to have insert mode mappings/abbreviations for them. VimTeX therefore
> provides a list of such mappings that are enabled by default, see
> |g:vimtex_imaps_list|
> ...
> It is of course possible to customize the list of mappings. First, one may
> specifically disable the entire imaps feature with |g:vimtex_imaps_enabled| or
> specific default mappings through |g:vimtex_imaps_disabled|. ...

Thus, we can remove these mappings with

- either `let g:vimtex_imaps_enabled = 0`, which disables all imaps set by vimtex,
- or `let g:vimtex_imaps_disabled = ['B','-','c','f','b','/']` which disables only specific imaps.

Comment: You were exactly right! I am realy impressed with all of your vim/ulti snips knowledge!. I got it to work with the first of your suggestions, however, the second one doesn't seem to work. I added `let g:vimtex_imaps_disabled = ['#']` to my .vimrc and it did not change the behaviour. Was I suppose to do that? Apologies for my incompetence with a lot of this...

Comment: I just realised that I was supposed to copy 'let g:vimtex_imaps_disabled = ['B','-','c','f','b','/']'. Thank you very much! You are amazing! My question has been answered.

Comment: @MathsWizzard Thank you for the kind words :) Well, many on this site surpass me, and I have benefited from their knowledge. Hopefully the pointers written here will be helpful when you encounter similar problems in future! Cheers!